# XML Parsing Subtle Error?

Tags: java, xml

I'm writing a program in Java that escapes certain XML chars (e.g. escape quotation with `&quot;`).

In the spec there is this statement:

You are asked to escape special characters. For example,

```
input: "Hello World!"

output: &quot;Hello World!&quot;
```

**There is a small technical error here, what is it?**

Apparently there is an error present in this process that I'm unaware of. Does this have to do with unparsed XML and parsed XML?

Thanks. Sorry for the vague description, I'm just as confused, let me know if you need more info about the actual program.

Comment: 3. You are fixing a bug where documents (represented as a String) are failing to be converted to proper xml. This problem can occur because either:
A. Certain characters fail in the xml, or
B. Documents passed in have a length > 100 characters (they’re small documents)

You want to escape these special characters. For simplicity, there are 5 characters that need escaping:

(Shows a table of 5 chars (&, ", ', >, < ) and their respective escape chars.

Write a method replaceSpecialChars to fix this bug

Comment: I've already written the code to do this and it works, but I don't know the answer to the question in my post.

Comment: Can you provide some more text from your spec where it says "there's a technical error here"? Please keep the text from your spec separate from your own comments; would help in understanding better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String input = "\"Hello World!\"";     
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;"));
// Output: &quot;Hello World!&quot;
```

You will need to escape the following charecters:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Take a look at [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax)

Comment: Thanks, so I've actually done the coding implementation, what I'm asking refers to the xml framework and how conceptual background behind just escaping the double quotes with &quot; has a small error involved. I think it has something to do with the way XML is parsed. Can you explain to me how parsing and char escapes work in XML?

Comment: Thanks, I think the "technical error" may be referring to parsing comments. Do comments <!-- need to be escaped?

Comment: it starts with '<' so it has to be escaped